# How I can find all string substring in file and then manipulate with it? - Python

Tags: python

I have a problem. I want to read this file
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/852226751832653864/870341903923695626/map.txt

And find all "targetname" lines and then finding out what comes next of targetname. For example,

"targetname" "rope01"

I want to know "rope01", and in .txt file there are multiple amount of substrings. And then I want to manipulate with rope01. How I can do it?

```
import re

value = '"targetname" "test"'
text = value[13:]
print(text)

#map_itself = open('map.txt', 'r') 

with open('map.txt', 'rb') as map_itself:
for line in map_itself:
    if '"targetname"'.encode() in map_itself:
        print("I found it!")
```

This code is pretty stupid and it can't even find any "targetname". However, they are existing in .txt. (CTRL + F to find "targetname" since it's not on top)

Comment: This isn't a plain text file. It looks like a [bsp](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_BSP_File_Format) file. Try to [decompile](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Decompiling_Maps) it first.

Comment: No I don't need to decompile it. I have to edit it. Trust me I know what i'm doing